# How to control the number of dynamc instances?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a php gae app. I have configured it the following way:

1. front instance class F1
2. minimum automatic, maximum of 1 idle instances
3. pending latency 6s - 14.6s
4. memcache shared
5. no page speed service

My concerns are:

1. Even though I have specified a pending latency in the range 6s-14s, the latency for each of the instances is generally less than 1s. Why? Shouldn't it be over 6s?
   [image]
2. It seems I have no control over the number of maximum dynamic instances that run at any given time. There are about 4-7 dynamic instances running simultaneously during the day.
   [image]
3. The app spends 28 instance hours in 11hrs.

How do I control the number of dynamic instances and have the app running smoothly within 28 instance hours?

Comment: Please post you backend config file.

Comment: I have no idea what a backend config file is :(

Comment: This is how appengine works.  You cant limit the number of instances.  Php handler is noth threaded so an instance is created for each request.  About all you can do is increase your pending latency and optimise your code more. For instance don't serve images from php code - I don't know if you can even do such a thing from php :-)  You won't have a back end config file unless you wrote it yourself so don't bother about that.